# Addition for binary natural numbers using primitive recursion

Tags: haskell

Given binary natural numbers, with a zero case a "twice" case and a "twice plus one" case. How can one express addition using primitive recursion (using only the function `foldBNat`)?

```hs
-- zero | n * 2 | n * 2 + 1
data BNat = Z | T BNat | TI BNat
  deriving (Show)

foldBNat :: BNat -> t -> (BNat -> t -> t) -> (BNat -> t -> t) -> t
foldBNat n z t ti =
  case n of
    Z -> z
    T m -> t m (foldBNat m z t ti)
    TI m -> ti m (foldBNat m z t ti)

div2 :: BNat -> BNat
div2 n = foldBNat n Z (\m _ -> m) (\m _ -> m)

pred :: BNat -> BNat
pred n = foldBNat n Z (\_ r -> TI r) (\m _ -> T m)

succ :: BNat -> BNat
succ n = foldBNat n (TI Z) (\m _ -> TI m) (\_ r -> T r)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea: To compute `a + b`, we need to increment `b` `a` times. So:

```
0 + b = b
1 + b = succ b
2 + b = succ (succ b)
3 + b = succ (succ (succ b))
...
```

We might start out by writing

```
plus a b = foldBNat a b (\m r -> ...
```

But here we get stuck: `m` represents half of `a` (since `a = T m` here, i.e. `a = 2 * m`) and `r` is the result of incrementing `b` `m` times (i.e. `m + b`). There's nothing useful we can do with that. What we want is `a + b = 2*m + b`, which we can't directly obtain from `m + b`. Applying `T` would only give us `2 * (m + b) = 2*m + 2*b`, which is too big, and according to the rules we can't directly recurse on `plus` to compute `m + (m + b) = 2*m + b`.

What we need is a more direct way of manipulating the number of `succ` operations.

Idea: Don't compute a number directly; instead compute a function (that increments its argument a certain number of times). So:

```
incBy 0 = id
incBy 1 = succ
incBy 2 = succ . succ
incBy 3 = succ . succ . succ
...
```

We can implement that directly:

```
incBy :: BNat -> (BNat -> BNat)
incBy n = foldBNat n id (\_ r -> r . r) (\_ r -> succ . r . r)
```

Here `r . r` gives us a function that increments a number twice as often as `r` does (by applying `r` twice).

Now we can simply define addition as:

```
plus :: BNat -> BNat -> BNat
plus n m = (incBy n) m
```

(which happens to be redundant because `plus = incBy`).

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I was hoping there would be a more efficient way to do addition, but I guess primitive recursion is the problem here? Would structural recursion allow for a more efficient algorithm? What about general recursion?

Comment: To answer my own comment, using structural/general recursion you can do much better.